# Yet another "finite 'xlim' values" question

Tags: r, plot

I know there are a million answered questions out there about the plot.window error "need finite 'xlim' values" but I have yet to find one that works for me or applies to my specific error so I'm asking for help. I'm sorry if this does turn out to be a duplicate question!

So I have a dataset "data" with a few continuous variables (in this case, we are only working with "CESD_score"). None of the observations are NA. Here's an example set:

```
CESD_score
12
15
10
4
16
8
```

I'm trying to plot a qqplot with qqline and I can visualize it when I'm using the gui/console but it fails when I try to plot it to save as png. Here's my code:

```
attach(data)
qq1 <- qqnorm(data$CESD_score, main="CESD Score Q-Q Plot", xlab="Theoretical Quantiles", ylab="CESD Score", plot.it = TRUE, datax = FALSE, xlim = c(-2,2))
qq1 <- qqline(data$CESD_score, datax = FALSE, distribution = qnorm, probs = c(0.25,0.75), qtype = 7, col = "red4", xlim = c(-2,2))
png("C:/Users/Desktop/CESDqq.png")
plot(qq1)
dev.off()
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

First of all, I'm confused why I'm getting the "need finite 'xlim' values" error since I've specified xlim values that reflect my data. Secondly, I'm not sure why I'm getting the other errors.

Any thoughts? What am I missing?

Thanks again for your answers and I'm sorry if this turns out to be a silly question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of overwriting `qq1`, just put both the calls to `qqnorm()` and `qqline()` inside the `png()` call:

```
png("c:/users/ccarpenter/desktop/test.png")
  qqnorm(data$CESD_score, main="CESD Score Q-Q Plot", xlab="Theoretical Quantiles", ylab="CESD Score", plot.it = TRUE, datax = FALSE, xlim = c(-2,2))
  qqline(data$CESD_score, datax = FALSE, distribution = qnorm, probs = c(0.25,0.75), qtype = 7, col = "red4", xlim = c(-2,2))
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked and it's simple (IMPORTANT since I'm new to R). You're awesome!